# How do I 'abort session' from Fiddler in C#?

Tags: c#, http, silverlight, fiddler

In Fiddler you can right click a URL in the capturing data grid and select 'Abort Session'. How does this work? can you abort a session in C# using HttpClient?

The problem I'm having is that I'm only allowed to have a maximum of 25 connections to my 'multipart/x-mixed-replace' stream that has an unlimited content length (live video stream). On the 26th connection I will be stuck await a response from,

```
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
```

This problem only occurs in Silverlight, a WPF application can have unlimited connections. Fiddler 'Abort session' was the only way I could pass 25 connections in Silverlight.

**EDIT:**

This seems to be a problem only in Silverlight

Comment: You mean something like [CancelPendingRequests()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.cancelpendingrequests.aspx)?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi CancelPendingRequests() doesn't work, I'll update my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think your real question is: `How can I cancel a request in Silverlight?` since using Fiddler for this purpose is pretty much a hack.

To cancel a request in FiddlerCore, you would call its `Abort()` method. In Fiddler, that method isn't public, but you could get the same effect by invoking `oSession.oResponse.pipeServer.End()`.